# Spring: Getting FactoryBean object instead of FactoryBean.getObject()

Tags: java, spring, factory, spring-batch

**Short question:** If I have class that impelemnts FactoryBean interface, how can I get from FactoryBean object itself instead of FactoryBean.getObject()?

**Long question:** I have to use 3-rd party Spring based library which is hardly use FactoryBean interface. Right now I always must configure 2 beans:

```
<!-- Case 1-->
<bean id="XYZ" class="FactoryBean1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="steps">
        <bean class="FactoryBean2">
            <property name="itemReader" ref="aName"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="aName" class="com.package.ClassName1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="objectContext">
        <bean class="com.package.ABC"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Case 2-->
<bean id="XYZ2" class="FactoryBean1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="steps">
        <bean class="FactoryBean2">
            <property name="itemReader" ref="aName2"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="aName2" class="com.package.ClassName1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="objectContext">
        <bean class="com.package.QWE"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Actyually defintion of a bean with name "XYZ" (compare with "XYZ2") never will be changed, but because of factory nature I must copy the code for each configuration.
Definition of a bean with name "aName" always will be new (i.e. each configuration will have own objectContext value).

I would like to simplify the configuration have a single factory bean (remove "XYZ2" and rid of link to "aName"):

```
<bean id="XYZ" class="FactoryBean1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="steps">
        <bean class="FactoryBean2"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="aName" class="com.package.ClassName1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="objectContext">
        <bean class="com.package.ABC"/>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="aName2" class="com.package.ClassName1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="objectContext">
        <bean class="com.package.QWE"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Unfortunately, it's not as simple as I expect. I suppose to glue factory (i.e. XYZ bean from the example) with necessary objects (i.e. "aName", "aName2") at runtime.
The approach doesn't work because when I ask Spring for FactoryBean object it returns to me FactoryBean.getObject() which impossible to instanciate at that time because of missing itemReader value.

I hope that SpringSource foresee my case I can somehome "hook" FactoryBean.getObject() call to provide all necessary properties at runtime.

Another complexity that disturb me a bit it's chains of Factories (Factory1 get an object from Factory2 that I have to "hook" at runtime).

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the `&` (ampersand), not the At-symbol, see Spring Framework documentation: [Customizing instantiation logic using FactoryBeans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

```
<property name="factoryBean" ref="&amp;theFactoryBean" />
```

Comment: Did you really check it? I've tried this way and it fails with exception like:
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "theFactoryBean" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: @wax: thanks, of course you are right, the XML must be escaped properly. I've corrected it

Comment: Just don't try this inside an EL expression.  I have a bug in for it :)  #{&amp;theFactoryBean}  does not work :(

Answer (score 2):

You can get the factory bean itself using the `&` syntax in the spring config:

```
<property name="factoryBean" ref="&theFactoryBean" />
```

as opposed to:

```
<property name="createdBean" ref="theFactoryBean" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work as you described. The correct answer is below.