# How to inject FactoryBean instead of object it produces?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have following Spring config (version of Spring is 3.0.3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="theFactoryBean" class="wax.MyFactoryBean"/>

   <bean id="factoryBeanUser" class="wax.FactoryBeanUser">
       <!-- what should be placed here?-->
   </bean>

</beans>
```

I have instance of `FactoryBean` implementation and some other instance. I need Spring to inject to other instance `FactoryBean`, not the object it produces.

There are two possible ways to solve it.

First one, obvious and malfunctional:

```
 <bean id="factoryBeanUser" class="wax.FactoryBeanUser">
    <property name="myFactoryBean" ref="&theFactoryBean"/>
</bean>
```

With this config Spring throws following exception on start:

```
    [skipped irrelevant part]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "theFactoryBean" must end with the ';' delimiter.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1414)
```

I found  this solution [Spring: Getting FactoryBean object instead of FactoryBean.getObject()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655140/spring-getting-factorybean-object-instead-of-factorybean-getobject), this question is maked as answered and four people voted for it. So I assume that this solution might work, but currently there is something wrong in my code.

Second one, working but awkward:

```
public class FactoryBeanUser implements ApplicationContextAware{

private MyFactoryBean myFactoryBean;

   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        myFactoryBean = (MyFactoryBean)applicationContext.getBean("&theFactoryBean");
   }
}
```

My question is it possible to make first approach functional or I should stick with a second way?

Comment: I don't believe the reference name can begin with an ampersand.  I'd remove that and try again.  The reference in this case needs to be the bean name of the factory bean.

Comment: @duffymo If you're right then people who voted for answer to another similar topic was completely wrong :) Anyway, if I change reference name to a name of the factory bean, Spring injects value that `FactoryBean` produces. This is actually what `FactoryBean` is made for.

Comment: I guess I'll learn something here as well; I've never done it.  I thought the app context was the factory - what do you need another for?

Comment: @duffymo in case you want some complex instantiation logic. To be honest, for all the years I've used this feature only twice, but it's very useful when you need it. And many, many framework classes are actually factories.

Comment: I agree, Bozho, but I think it's possible to do all this under Spring's control.  You're really describing a Builder pattern.

Comment: @duffymo I think you're confusing `BeanFactory` and `FactoryBean`. `BeanFactory` creates beans by configuration and resolves dependencies for these beans.
`FactoryBean` is a completely another story. Beans which implements this interface are supposed to produce objects of another type. This interface is widely used in all kind of infrastructure beans.

Comment: For example, when you need to need to implement remote invokations via HTTP you need to configure `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean`. In its configuration you specify service interface, and finally this `FactoryBean` returns you a proxy which implements service interface and allows to invoke methods on remote server transparently. Here you can find more information about it - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-httpinvoker

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems the XML parser interprets the ampersand (&) as a start of an XML-entity. You can try using `ref="&amp;theFactoryBean"`.

The [spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension) is not clear whether this syntax is allowed in an xml file, or only with programatic lookup. But then the xml configuration is used by the app context, so I assume the `&amp;` should work (although it seems it has not been the best choice for a special symbol)

Here's why I'd suggest another thing - if you really need the factory bean rather than its product, create another bean, that does not implement `FactoryBean`, define a method `createObject()` or something like that, and use it in all factories that need it.

A sidenote - better reference the xsd with the version included:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

Comment: @wax - just for the record - the `&amp;` worked? Or the alternative suggestion?

Comment: yes, `&amp;` works. 
I considered another thing you suggested. In my real application I already have `BeanFactory` definition which needs to be slightly modified to solve my issue. That is why I think it would be better to reuse it than create another bean.