# "Bean named XXX must be of type[XXX], but was actually of type[XXX]"

Tags: spring, integration, mybatis

when I integrate spring and mybatis, I encountered a error output, saying that:

> Bean named 'sqlSessionFactory' must be of type [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean], but was actually of type [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory]

here is my code snippet:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_mybatis_integration/spring_config.xml");
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = context.getBean("sqlSessionFactory", org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.class);
```

here is my bean definition in xml:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="configLocation" value="spring_mybatis_integration/mybatis_config.xml"></property>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

as you can see, both in java code and in xml file, I associate the bean `sqlSessionFactory` with class `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean`, why does the error output tell me another non-relative class name `org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory`?

Thanks a lot!

#### Version Info:

- mybatis 3.1.1
- spring 3.2.0
- mybatis-spring 1.1.1

Comment: Enable logging of springframework when you launch your ApplicationContext and take a look at bean definition override logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to access`SqlSessionFactoryBean` via dependency injection, normally we work with the objects created by the Factory Beans, not the Factory Beans themselves, in this case the Factory Bean returns a `DefaultSqlSessionFactory` instance.

See [Customizing instantiation logic with the FactoryBean Interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

But if you really want to access the `FactoryBean` instance, you should use ampersand symbol `&` see [Spring: Getting FactoryBean object instead of FactoryBean.getObject()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655140/spring-getting-factorybean-object-instead-of-factorybean-getobject)

Yes, the concept of the Factory Beans that return factories may be a bit confusing, but that is how things work in Spring.

So it's likely `SqlSessionFactory` instead of the `SqlSessionFactoryFactoryBean` is what you want.

**update:** actually MyBatis even explained this in the documentation on [SqlSessionFactoryBean](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/factorybean.html)

> Note that SqlSessionFactoryBean implements Spring's FactoryBean
>   interface (see section 3.8 of the Spring documentation). This means
>   that the bean Spring ultimately creates is not the
>   SqlSessionFactoryBean itself, but what the factory returns as a result
>   of the getObject() call on the factory. In this case, Spring will
>   build an SqlSessionFactory for you at application startup and store it
>   with the name sqlSessionFactory

Comment: thx!The thing I want most is indeed sqlSessionFactory instead of SqlSessionFactoryFactoryBean. I'm a beginner to the integration of mybatis and spring, what should I do to get a Mapper interface(which is bind to an implementation that I can call methods on) after I define a MapperFactoryBean in Spring xml file?

Comment: PS. the motivation of I retrieving sqlSessionFactory is to get a mapper interface(DAO) which is bind to the mapper.xml, is there a more decent way to do that? thanks~

Comment: @Judking, I'm not a mybatis user, but you should not retrieve SqlSessionFactory instances from the application container manually - you should create dedicated classes(Services, DAOS) and inject their dependencies via Spring(it is the Spring container who sets their property values and provides constructor arguments for autowiring), for example see how it's done for hypothetic `FooServiceImpl` class in the official documentation http://www.mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html - theres a `MapperFactoryBean` declared in XML and the mapper it creates is injected to the FooServiceImpl instance.

Comment: I got it, **MapperFactoryBean** acts just like a proxy to the DAO interface. But how does spring do all that stuff for user without user having to write any java code? where is the start point when spring do all that stuff? Thanks for your time friend, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547148/whats-the-mechanism-of-xml-in-spring-during-the-lifecycle-of-a-program): what's the mechanism of xml in spring during the lifecycle of a program?

Comment: Spring container configuration is a set of entities called Bean Definitions. When you provide an xml file, XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader parses it and populates bean definition registry of the container. Bean definitions contain information for class creation - for example  fully qualified class name and arguments.They also define the lifecycle of the bean. Knowing the class name is enough to create it via reflection API in java.

Comment: When you delegate  some aspect of application logic to another interface that's called Inversion of control. For example in Java we do not deallocate memory explicitly - we allow the garbage collector to do it. Spring does the same thing but for the creation(and dependency injection) of objects. You can read more about IoC and DI in Martin J Fowler article http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: oops i missed the link, in that case property placeholder configurer is bean definition post processor - post processors are instantiated before other beans so they can modify bean definitions in the registry. That is well described in the Spring reference documentation.