# Bean named X is expected to be of type 'java.lang.Runnable' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'

Tags: java, spring

Spring is giving me below error, but can't figure out why is it !

Note: There is no bean definition in xml file for this.

> Bean named 'resetDatabase' is expected to be of type
>   'java.lang.Runnable' but was actually of type
>   'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'

```
@Bean
Runnable resetDatabase() throws Exception
{
    if (env.acceptsProfiles("prof"))
    {
        return resetDatabase_H2();
    }
    else
    {
        // return resetDatabase_H2();
        return resetDatabase_Postgresql();
    }
}
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545872/bean-named-xxx-must-be-of-typexxx-but-was-actually-of-typexxx) as well but couldn't find any solution for my case

Comment: What is the type of the Object returned by `resetDatabase_H2();` and `resetDatabase_Postgresql();`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Runnable. However resetDatabase_Postgresql always returns null.

Comment: Then you have to investigate why ` resetDatabase_Postgresql` is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

If `resetDatabase_Postgresql` can return `null`, then you can wrap it into an optional and return a runnable that does nothing in that case:

```java
return Optional.ofNullable(resetDatabase_Postgresql()).orElse(() -> {});
```