# Multiple SharedEntityManagerBeans and ApplicationContext.getBean issue

Tags: spring, proxy, applicationcontext

I have two databases which I want to access from my `Spring` application. I configured two `SharedEntityManagerBean` for both databases.  Here is the config:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="xxx" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="xxx" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager1">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager2">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory1"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:packagesToScan="xxxxxx"
        ....
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory2"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:packagesToScan="xxxxx"
        ...
</bean>


<bean id="entityManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean" >            
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource1"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
...
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceOntology"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
...
</bean>
```

I have two `EntityLocators` which are not managed by `Spring` that access entities in each of the corresponding databases. They look something like that:

```
public class SpringEntitiyLocator1 {

    private EntityManager em;

    public SpringEntitiyLocator1() {

    }

    private EntityManager getEM() {
        if (em == null) {
            ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalServletContext());
            SharedEntityManagerBean bean =  context.getBean("entityManager1",SharedEntityManagerBean.class);
            em = bean.getObject();
        }
        return em;
    }
}
```

When I have only one `SharedEntityManagerBean` defined in my applicationContext the call to `getBean()` works fine. However once I have both `SharedEntityManagerBean`s defined I get the error:

`Bean named 'x' must be of type [y], but was actually of type [$Proxy]`

I read on SO that I should use `cglib` proxying by adding `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true"/>` to my application.xml.

Is that the best solution ?

When I add that line I get `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable` errors.
Do I need `aspectj` for that?

**EDIT:**

In case I have only one `SharedEntityManagerBean` defined I can call `getBean(SharedEntityManagerBean.class)`. This works fine.
I debugged the code and it seems that this call will call `getBean("&entityManager1",SharedEntityManagerBean.class)` (note **&**) .

However when I pass the name `getBean("EntityManager1",SharedEntityManagerBean.class)` I get a type cast exception.

Having both `SharedEntityManagerBean`s defined and call `getBean` without a name also causes an exception (can't find a bean with that name).

So my current workaround is to call: `getBean("&entityManager1",SharedEntityManagerBean.class)` and `getBean("&entityManager2",SharedEntityManagerBean.class)`

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently `SharedEntityManagerBean` is a `FactoryBean` and for that I have to add **&** before the bean name to retrieve the `SharedEntityManagerBean`.

Alternatively I could probably just call:

`em = context.getBean("entityManager",EntityManager.class);`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655140/spring-getting-factorybean-object-instead-of-factorybean-getobject) and [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?42313-tx-annotation-driven-autoproxies-everything) for reference.